# window load event is not firing on page load using Enter key

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, onload-event

I have below html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="http://differentDomain/main.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

And the main.js has following code:

```
window.onload = function {
   console.log('event fired!!');
}
```

Now *event fired!!* is getting logged if I use relaod button to load the page. However, it is not happening if I hit the URL using enter key in the address field.

In the course of testing, I get to add new local javascript file in the page like:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="http://differentDomain/main.js"></script>
     <script src="http://sameDomain/local.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Surprisingly after adding the above file, load event started firing and *event fired!!* is getting logged in both cases.

Firstly please let me know why event is not getting fired for first time.
Secondly how adding a new file after the existing file makes difference in event getting fired.

Note: I could observe in the network tab that the local file is not getting cached but main.js does.